# Getting entries from multiple categories

Tags: categories, relations, relatedto

I have two categories, Annual Reviews and Publications.
I want to get all entries from these and paginate them.

The code I am using is fine for one category - both work individually, but as soon as the criteria contains two categories i get zero results no errors. I have tried using 'one()' on the initial categories as I only want category returned. 
What am I missing? (using Craft Pro 3.1.31)

```
{% set publications = craft.categories.group('resources').slug('publications') %}
{% set annualreviews = craft.categories.group('resources').slug('annualreviews') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries({
section: 'resources',
relatedTo: [
'and',
{ targetElement: publications },
{ targetElement: annualreviews }
]
}).limit('10').orderBy('title') %}

{% paginate entries as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're wanting `'and'`? Or are you meaning "get all entries that have a `publications` _or_ `annualreviews` category?

Comment: OK resolved now - client slug mis-spelling! thx

Answer (score 1):

OK resolved now - client slug mis-spelling! thx